# Programmatically updating fields in Mongo and Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that I'd like to update. The field is given programmatically, so I'd like to do something like this:

```
var update_string = 'coordinates.lat';
var update = function(value, id, update_string) {
  Collection.update({_id:id}, {$set:{update_string:value}})
}
```

That however does not work and just sets "update_string" to have value {{value}} in the object with _id {{id}} in the Collection. I also tried doing `var update_string = "'coordinates.lat'";` to no avail.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the key in your update `$set` parameter correctly:

```
var update = function(value, id, update_string) {
   var update_query = {};
   update_query[update_string] = value 
   Collection.update({_id:id}, {$set:update_query})
}
```

Basically without the modification above, If you used `{update_string:value}` you would be setting the value of `update_string`, not `coordinates.lat`.

Comment: Ohhhh, that makes sense. Thanks Akshat. Going to try this out when I get back and will give you cred.