# Return contents of one field (an array) from Mongodb document in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am working in Meteor and trying to retrieve just the contents of one field in a Mongodb document.  This particular field is an array.  I've read the Mongo docs and several related questions, but my projection just isn't working.  This is what I have:

User adds to array using the following form:

```
Template.One.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentId = this._id
        var oneProperties = {
            selections: $(e.target).find('[name=selection]').val()
        };
        Charts.update(currentId, ($addToSet: selections}, function() {});
    }
});
```

Resulting document:

```
{
    "_id": "some ID",
    "selections": ["A","B"]
}
```

Refer to array in a helper for a different template to access documents from a different collection.

```
Template.Two.helpers({
    comps: function() {
        var selected = Charts.findOne({_id:this._id}, {selections:1, _id:0});
        return Companies.find({ticker: {$in: selected}});
    }
});
```

When I run the Charts.findOne query above directly in the console, it returns the entire document, with no limitations.

If I replace `Charts.findOne({_id:this._id}, {selections:1, _id:0});` with simply `["A","B"]`, then everything else works perfectly.  So I know it is the projection itself.  I also can't tell if this query will return just need the array, which is what I need, or the name `selections:` as well.

Any thoughts very appreciated.

Comment: You need to programmatically create the entire object:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331216/programmatically-updating-fields-in-mongo-and-meteor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the selections field of the document, that should give you the array directly, not the entire document:

```
var selected = Charts.findOne({_id:this._id}, {selections:1, _id:0});
```

would give you `{ "selections": ["A","B"] }`

But

```
var selected = Charts.findOne({_id:this._id}, {selections:1, _id:0}).selected;
```

will give you the needed array

```
["A","B"]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Much simpler than I was making it.  The final query was: 
var selected = Charts.findOne({_id:this._id}).selections;