# Meteor 1.0 - Mongo queries using variables as key, including $inc

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm working with a large dataset that needs to be efficient with its Mongo queries. The application uses the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to calculate recommendations and runs in polynomial time, so efficiency is extremely important. The syntax is ES6, but everything is basically the same.

This is an approximation of the data I'm working with. An array of items and one item being matched up against the other items:

```
let items = ["pen", "marker", "crayon", "pencil"];
let match = "sharpie";
```

Eventually, we will iterate over `match` and increase the weight of the pairing by 1. So, after going through the function, my ideal data looks like this:

```
{
  sharpie: {
    pen: 1,
    marker: 1,
    crayon: 1,
    pencil: 1
  }
}
```

To further elaborate, the value next to each key is the `weight` of that relationship, which is to say, the number of times those items have been paired together. What I would like to have happen is something like this:

```
// For each in the items array, check to see if the pairing already
// exists. If it does, increment. If it does not, create it.
_.each(items, function(item, i) {  
  Database.upsert({ match: { $exist: true }}, { match: { $inc: { item: 1 } } });
})
```

The problem, of course, is that Mongo does not allow bracket notation, nor does it allow for variable names as keys (`match`). The other problem, as I've learned, is that Mongo also has problems with deeply nested `$inc` operators (`'The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$inc\' in \'3LhmpJMe9Es6r5HLs.$inc\' is not valid for storage.' }`).

Is there anything I can do to make this in as few queries as possible? I'm open to suggestions.

**EDIT**

I attempted to create objects to pass into the Mongo query:

```
    _.each(items, function(item, i) {
        let selector = {};
        selector[match] = {};
        selector[match][item] = {};

        let modifier = {};
        modifier[match] = {};
        modifier[match]["$inc"] = {};
        modifier[match]["$inc"][item] = 1

        Database.upsert(selector, modifier);
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. The `$inc` breaks the query and it won't let me go more than 1 level deep to change anything.

**Solution**

This is the function I ended up implementing. It works like a charm! Thanks Matt.

```
  _.each(items, function(item, i) {

    let incMod = {$inc:{}};
    let matchMod = {$inc:{}};

    matchMod.$inc[match] = 1;
    incMod.$inc[item] = 1;

    Database.upsert({node: item}, matchMod);
    Database.upsert({node: match}, incMod);
  });
```

Comment: Since you can't use variables directly in the arguments and bracket notation isn't supported, you have to do all the logic of programmatically creating your query object before calling your Mongo query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331216/programmatically-updating-fields-in-mongo-and-meteor

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny Thank you for your reply :) I tried using a query object but `$inc` does not appear to be functional when going that deep. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by `edge`? There's no `edge` operator in Mongo. Also, `modifier["edge"]["$inc"][item] = 1` has no defined variable `item`. Do you mean `el`?

Comment: You're not allowed to have `$` or `.` in your Mongo keys because they're special characters. Try this: `{'sharpie.pen': {$inc: 1}}`. The dot is a special character for specifying nested keys

Comment: @Chet So yes, that specific query will work, but it doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that I do not know in advance that the search terms will be "sharpie" and "pen". All I know is that there are two variables that can be named anything that I need to find in the database.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny Apologies. That code was just a copy-paste from my actual code. I've updated the function at the end to make it reflect the example. I've also shortened the expected output to make things easier. 

In the previous example, "edge" was just an index to make querying faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trouble comes from your ER model. a `sharpie` isn't a standalone entity, a sharpie is an item. The relationship between 1 item  and other items is such that 1 item has many items (1:M recursive) and each item-pairing has a weight.

Fully normalized, you'd have an items table & a weights table. The items table would have the items. The weights table would have something like `item1`, `item2`, `weight` (in doing so, you can have asymmetrical weighting, e.g. `sharpie:pencil = 1`, `pencil:sharpie = .5`, which is useful when calculating pushback in the FFA, but I don't think that applies in your case.

Great, now let's mongotize it.

When we say 1 item has many items, that "many" is probably not going to exceed a few thousand (think 16MB document cap). That means it's actually 1-to-few, which means we can nest the data, either using subdocs or fields.

So, let's check out that schema!

```
doc =
{
  _id: "sharpie",
  crayon: 1,
  pencil: 1
}
```

What do we see? `sharpie` isn't a key, it's a *value*. This makes everything easy. We leave the items as fields. The reason we don't use an array of objects is because this is faster & cleaner (no need to iterate over the array to find the matching `_id`).

```
var match = "sharpie";
var items = ["pen", "marker", "crayon", "pencil"];
var incMod = {$inc:{}};
var matchMod = {$inc:{}};
matchMod.$inc[match] = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  Collection.upsert({_id: items[i]}, matchMod);
  incMod.$inc[items[i]] = 1;  
}
Collection.upsert({_id: match}, incMod);
```

That's the easy part. The hard part is figuring out why you want to use an FFA for a suggestion engine :-P.

Comment: I will try to implement this now :) This looks promising!

Comment: It totally worked! Matt, you're the man! I'm not sure I entirely understand what's happening with `incMod` and `matchMod`, but it's running flawlessly.

I'm using FFA just for kicks :) I plan on implementing a few other algorithms as well.

Comment: When you have something like `{ $inc: { item: 1 }}` it's just an object with fields. Just like a regular JS object, you can add fields dynamically via bracket notation.

Second, take your inc mod out of the loop to reduce the number of touches to the database. For any "transaction" (I use that term loosely) you shouldn't touch the same doc more than once.

Third, what algo did you go with? collaborative filter?