# How to update multiple collection keys received as arguments?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to increase different values in my collection using the same code.

I'm trying to compute that in a function where the updated properties will depend on the parameters:

```
BuyEntitee : function(id_fb,entitee)
{
  var j = Joueur.findOne({id_fb:id_fb});
  var prix_current = j["prix_"+entitee];
  var update_query = {};

  update_query[entitee+"s"]     = j[entitee+"s"] + 1;
  update_query["prix_"+entitee] = Math.round(50*Math.pow(1.1,j[entitee+"s"]));

    Joueur.update( {id_fb:id_fb},  {
        $set: {update_query}
      }
    );

  j = Joueur.findOne({id_fb:id_fb}); // on recharge le jouer ... utile ??
  console.log('nbHumains : ' + j.humains+ ' query = '+JSON.stringify(update_query));
  return j.rochers;
}
```

But unfortunately, the query is 1 level too deep in the structure :

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.joueur.findOne()
{
    "_id" :
    "humains" : 12,
    "prix_humain" : 50,
    "update_query" : 
    {
            "humains" : 13,
            "prix_humain" : 157
    }
}
```

I'm creating the `update_query` object so that I can programmatically change the parameters in the update function (saw this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331216/programmatically-updating-fields-in-mongo-and-meteor)).

Is there a way to perform that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened is, in fact, a result of the ES6 syntactic sugar for specifying objects.

When you specified `{update_query}`, it was interpreted as an object with the key of `"update_query"` and the value of the variable `update_query`.

Therefore, it is the equivalent of:

```
Joueur.update( {id_fb:id_fb},  {
    $set: {
     update_query: update_query
    }
  }
);
```

What you really want is to assign the `update_query` itself to the `$set` key:

```
Joueur.update( {id_fb:id_fb},  {
    $set: update_query
  }
);
```

On a side note, you probably want to use the `$inc` modifier in order to increment the `entitee+"s"` by 1.

Comment: Godness, I shouldn't code when I'm too tired ... Thanks :)